# How many broadcast receiver can be used in Android application?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, broadcastreceiver

I am working on a project which is handling both email and chat functionality. For chat, I am using sockets and for mail functionality, I am using Java Mail Api. Now here's the problem, "For both functionalities, I need a broadcast receiver, so can I use two broadcast receiver in a single application.

Here is the code.

Android Manifest : -

```
<receiver android:name=".receivers.ChatMsgReceiver">
    <intent-filter android:priority="500">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
</intent-filter>
```

```
<receiver android:name=".receivers.EmailReceiver">
        <intent-filter android:priority="500">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Email receiver class file.

```
public class EmailReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    //My rest code goes here's

}
}
```

Chat Receiver class file.

```
public class ChatMsgReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    //My rest code goes here's

}
}
```

Comment: Are you having an issue with this code that makes you think you can't?

Comment: Yes because I am not able to listen to the broadcast, but when I merge both in single, it works, but I need two separate broadcast receivers.

Comment: OK, then you need to explain that better in your post because you certainly can use multiples. In one app, I have several running and working as expected.

Comment: And I just noticed they are registered for the same action. There is no reason to do this. So, if it is working fine in one Receiver, why would you want two?

Comment: For one receiver I want alarm manager to work after 5 sec and for another after 10 sec, So I want two different receivers. @codeMagic

Comment: Maybe an easier (and possibly cleaner) way is to have one receiver and set two alarms once the receiver is called.

Answer (score 3):

> so can I use two broadcast receiver in a single application.

Yes, you can.